# Make button 50% size of grid cell XamForms

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms, grid, width

I'm trying to make the grid cells exactly 50% of the width, which works fine. However, I want the buttons to be 50% within the cell and not expand to the size of the cell.

Xaml below, how to I modify the Button to be 50% width of the cell it is in.

```
            <Grid Padding="10,10,10,10">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <Button Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Text="Back" Command="" BackgroundColor="Red" TextColor="White" ></Button>
            <Button Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Text="Done" Command="" BackgroundColor="Green" TextColor="White"></Button>
        </Grid>
```

Comment: Add side margins to the buttons, also you could define the `Padding="10"` if they're the same :D

Comment: Is it possible to define as Auto on the buttton?

Comment: Why don't you make 4 columns instead of 2? Or you need to center your button with desired width?

Comment: I often do that sort of thing in code behind, I just find it easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> how to I modify the Button to be 50% width of the cell it is in.

You can put the Button into the **StackLayout** so that the width of the Button is half the width of the **GridCell**.

**Solution code:**

```
<Grid Padding="10,10,10,10">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="50*"></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="50*"></ColumnDefinition>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <StackLayout  Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalOptions="Center">
        <Button Text="Back" Command="{Binding .}" BackgroundColor="Red" TextColor="White"  ></Button>
    </StackLayout>
    <StackLayout Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalOptions="Center">
        <Button  Text="Done" Command="{Binding .}" BackgroundColor="Green" TextColor="White"></Button>
    </StackLayout>
</Grid>
```

[image]